# Want to Export-CSV variable with properties

Tags: powershell

I want to build a "~table" that holds information about various computer (e.g. Name, IP Address and MAC Address though more information could be added later). Here is what I have so far:

```
$Computers = "Server1", "Server2", "Server" #Eventually will get from file
$a = $Computers.length

$User = Read-Host "Enter Username"
$Cred = Get-Credential $User
cls

$ComputerInfo = @{NAME = 1..$a; IP_ADDR = 1..$a; MAC_ADDR = 1..$a}

$i = 0
ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
   $wmiquery = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computer $Computer -filter "IPEnabled='True'" -Credential $Cred

   $ComputerInfo.NAME[$i] = $Computer
   $ComputerInfo.IP_ADDR[$i] = $wmiquery.IPAddress[0]
   $ComputerInfo.MAC_ADDR[$i] = $wmiquery.MACAddress

   $i++
}
```

The code above provides me with the information I want. However, I'm having trouble exporting to csv file / displaying in table. If I simply type: `$ComputerInfo`. I get:

> Name     Value
>
> MAC_ADDR     {MAC1, MAC2, MAC3}
>
> IP_ADDR      {IP1, IP2, IP3}
>
> NAME         {Server1, Server2, Server3}

Not exactly what I'm looking for. I want something more like:

> NAME     IP_ADDR     MAC_ADDR
>
> [value]     [value]     [value]
>
> [value]     [value]     [value]
>
> [value]     [value]     [value]

If I export `$ComputerInfo` to CSV file it gets even goofier. I get

> TYPE System.Collections.Hashtable
>   "IsReadOnly","IsFixedSize","IsSynchronized","Keys","Values","SyncRoot","Count"
>   "False","False","False","System.Collections.Hashtable+KeyCollection","System.Collections.Hashtable+ValueCollection","System.Object","3"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Overall I would make the following adjustments below. A few things I changed around:

1. change your credential prompt to one line since `Get-Credential` can provide a message
2. Created the table as a `psobject`, it makes it much easier to work with and referencing columns to set values.
3. In using the `psobject` it removes the need to index into the array (e.g. using `column[0]`)
4. I added in testing if the computer was on the network before you try connecting to get information (just good practice).

When you want to add more columns to your table just expand the `$props` variable with your columns, and populate it in your `foreach` loop.

Output of this script just with my local computer:
[image]
[image]

Then to just show what it will output if I just `ConvertTo-Csv`:
[image]

```
$UserCred = (Get-Credential -Message "Enter username")

$props = [ordered]@{NAME="";IP_ADDR="";MAC_ADDR=""}
$ComputerInfo = New-Object psobject -property $props

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {
    if (Test-Connection $computer) {
        $wmiquery = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computer $Computer -filter "IPEnabled='True'" -Credential $Cred
        $ComputerInfo.NAME = $computer
        $ComputerInfo.IP_ADDR = $wmiquery.IPAddress[0]
        $ComputerInfo.MAC_ADDR = $wmiquery.MACAddress
    }
    else{
        Write-Warning "$($computer) not found on the network"
    }
}

$ComputerInfo
```

**EDIT**

One thing to just add that you will see a difference with your `$computerinfo` versus mine above is the TypeName. If you pipe it to `Get-Member` your object will return as `System.Collections.Hashtable`, where mine is going to return as a `System.Management.Automation.PSCustomObject`. The `PSCustomObject` will return each column in your table as a `NoteProperty` type that you can use in your script as you build onto it (e.g. querying the domain for Computer information).

Comment: Your solutions does provide me the information I want in the desired format but now `$ComputerInfo` only holds information on a single computer even when `$ComputerInfo` contains multiple computers. I will tweak a bit and see what I can come up with.

Comment: I have modified your code slightly do what I need it to do. Also, accepted your answer as solution.

Answer (score 0):

Code below does what I need it to do. Slightly modified version of code provided by Shawn Melton. Changed `$ComputerInfo` to array, `ForEach` updated to add data into `$ComputerInfo` array.

```
$Computers = "Server1", "Server2, Server3"
$a = $Computers.length
$Cred = (Get-Credential)
$i=0
$ComputerInfo = 1..$a
$props = @{NAME = ""; IP_ADDR = ""; MAC_ADDR = ""}

ForEach ($Computer in $Computers) {

    $ComputerInfo[$i] = New-Object psobject -property $props
    $wmiquery = get-wmiobject win32_networkadapterconfiguration -computer $Computer -filter "IPEnabled='True'" -Credential $Cred
    $ComputerInfo[$i].NAME = $computer
    $ComputerInfo[$i].IP_ADDR = $wmiquery.IPAddress[0]
    $ComputerInfo[$i].MAC_ADDR = $wmiquery.MACAddress
    $i++
}

$ComputerInfo
```